Computing whether two finite groups are isomorphic (in C++)
I need to algorithmically compute whether two given finite groups are isomorphic. Usually I only have generators of these groups.
The groups can get quite large as I'm working with subgroups of $S_{32}$. Are the existing algorithms efficient in such cases too? There's IsomorphismGroups in GAP which is said that can get time consuming, for that it's also mentioned RandomIsomorphismTest, which though, seems to be applicable only for polycyclic groups (or at least that's how I interpreted). Nonetheless, I'm not looking for the function in GAP. My program is in C++, hence I'd either need to do this by hand or find an appropriate third party that implements such algorithms. Trying to see how GAP does it was my first thought, but I couldn't find the implementation details of these algorithms on github.
So could you point me what references to look at?

You could consider the order of some elements in $G,H\subseteq S_{32}$. Often you'll find an element of order $n$ in $G$, but none in $H$. Then you are already done.

@DietrichBurde that helps rule out the non isomorphic groups but is it efficient and reliable enough to determine whether two groups are actually isomorphic?

No, of course not. But sometimes you don't really need the full isomorphism test. What have you tried so far?

@DietrichBurde initially I was thinking that if the generators of equal size generate groups of equal order and if the orders of the individual elements in these generators are equal then the groups are isomorphic. But that's not so. On this note, there's an algorithm developed by C. Sims (my uni notes call it Sims' algorithm) that allows to create a "strong" generator from a generator set, which allows to uniquely represent each element of the generated group and it's basically a table of elements. I feel like one could test the isomorphism using strong generator sets, but I'm not sure how.

I can't seem to find the original source of that algorithm though and my notes aren't in English. But I think it must be a special case of Schreier-Sims but it's basically about considering factor sets in a stabilizer chain and list one element per coset forming a table. When it comes to permutations each next subgroup in the chain fixes one more number in the permutations. This allows to easily test whether an element belongs to a particular coset hence the algorithm.

[I implemented GAP's version of the isomorphism test.]
What you are asking is a hard problem, and one that will possibly require tradeoff between coding effort and practical performance. Assuming you understand the algorithms in full detail, and already have implementations of basic functionality for permutation groups (the Schreier-Sims algorithms, which you allude to, which allows for testing element membership in subgroups and to test for a map on generators being a homomorphism), I estimate that it will easily take you 1-2 weeks to implement a basic version, and 1-2 months to implement a fuller version of the isomorphism test. Frankly, it will be far less work to link to GAP, than trying to write an isomorphism test on your own from scratch.
There are basically two algorithms: The simpler (easier to implement, less performant) tests possible generator images. It is described, e.g. in section 9.1. of D. F. Holt et al., Handbook of computational group theory. Chapman & Hall/CRC Press
The more sophisticated algorithm is given in J. J. Cannon and D. F. Holt, J. Symb. Comput. 35, No. 3, 241--267,
https://doi.org/10.1016/S0747-7171(02)00133-5 . It is implemented in the file lib/autsr.gi in GAP.
Beyond the routines for permutation group management, it requires e.g. the ability to compute 1-cohomology groups, module automorphism groups, and to perform a backtrack search within an automorphism group.
Describing this algorithm in more detail is not really feasible here -- once you have read and fully understood the Handbook I mentioned above, it would take an extra 2-3 pages.
